# Bootstrap dropdown not firing click event if elements are created in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to use a normal Bootstrap dropdown menu with links, but I want to fire Jquery code instead of having the link redirect as usual. The list will be dynamically created from a database table.

I can get this working fine if i define the list as below.

```
$(".sitedropdown").append('<li><a class="sitelink" href="#">s</a></li>');
$(".sitedropdown").append('<li><a class="sitelink" href="#">asd</a></li>');
```

As soon as i try run a loop though to add the elements, the click event magically stops working.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj,function(index,arr){
$(".sitedropdown").append('<li><a class="sitelink" href="#">'+arr.wpname+'</a></li>');
});
```

I have searched all over for this but cant find anything.
Before anyone asks, yes i am using jquerys ON event to deal with dynamically added elements.

Comment: which click event? Post relevant code, how do you bind event?

Comment: Hey Wolff,
Just trying to use the click event for the dropdown list.
    $(".sitelink").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("bob");}
    );

Comment: So then try delegating event: `$(".sitedropdown").on("click", ".sitelink", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert("bob");});`

Comment: Aha! Thanks alot! Obviously i need to read up more about On!
If you can post that as an answer Wolff, ill mark it answered, else ill post your comment in 8 hours and do the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So then try delegating event: $(".sitedropdown").on("click", ".sitelink", function(e){ >e.preventDefault(); alert("bob");}); – A. Wolff

Wolff got it right off the bat.

Thanks again